# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote some code using Regular Expressions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"ch/js/789747b7/scriptSearch.js"",videoJsSrc:""res/batch/js/3c9a6ee1/scriptVideo.js"",apiFormAppJSSrc:""res/batch/js/9fa7e22b/apiFormApp.js"",easyXDMJs:""res/batch/js/8f3e66db/easyXDM.min.js"",nativeHooksSrc:""res/batch/js/539ea638/nativeHooks.js"",gwtHash:""1bcb94eb"",jsessionId:";
            Match output = Regex.Match(input, @"gwtHash:""(.*?)""").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'   C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   14  28  ConsoleApplication1
```

What's wrong?

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property `Value` has type of `string`. So, you need either assign result of `Regex.Match` method to your `Match` object, and then write it's `Value` to console

```
Match output = Regex.Match(input, @"gwtHash:""(.*?)""");
Console.WriteLine(output.Value);
```

Or change `output` variable type to string:

```
string output = Regex.Match(input, @"gwtHash:""(.*?)""").Value;
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

---

To get `1bcb94eb` use

```
Match output = Regex.Match(input, @"gwtHash:""(.*?)""");
if (output.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(output.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks how to put only 1bcb94eb to a var?

Comment: Use `output.Groups[1].Value`